# Extract Minimum date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column Date where some cells have one date, some two or more.

From multiple dates in one cell of the Date column I want to extract minimum date or if it one date then retain the date.

Could someone please help me. Below is the sample.

[image]

Comment: Ideally you should change your design and get each pipe separated date onto a separate row.

Comment: Please don't use imaged for data, use formatted text.

Comment: Is first date always the earliest? That would be fairly simple string manipulation.

Comment: Sorry for using image for data. No, earliest date can be in sitting anywhere in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function

```
SELECT Date, MIN(s.value) AS Min_Date
FROM <your table> d 
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.Date, '|') AS s
GROUP BY Date;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XdEWGKd7).